# front end : give option but blank default after click there is option or blank input but if we click there is list

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

in front end how to make option but default is blank, or blank input but if we click there is many list inside

i use laravel parsing in view

```php
<select name="province" id="province">
            @foreach ($province as $item)
                <option value="{{$item['province_id']}}">
                {{$item["province"]}}   
            </option>
            @endforeach
</select>
```

if i using CSS style option in not working when i click

```php
<select name="province" id="province">
            @foreach ($province as $item)
                <option style="display:none" value="{{$item['province_id']}}">
                {{$item["province"]}}   
            </option>
            @endforeach
</select>
```

in first is working but not showing blank as default
second code option is not working also showing first record as default

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are referring to? You need to pass an option outside the **foreach loop**

```
<select name="province" id="province">
  <option selected disabled> --select option -- </option>
  @foreach ($province as $item)
    <option style="display:none" value="{{$item['province_id']}}">
        {{$item["province"]}}   
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

oh i got the asnwer i add emty array and put into first array in controller

```
public function province(){
    //open model
    $tracking = new Tracking;
    //call provinsi
    $url = "https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province?";
    $province = $tracking->serverApi($url);
    $provinceJson = json_decode($province,true);
    $provinceJson =  $provinceJson["rajaongkir"]["results"];
    $arrEmty = [
        "province_id" => "",
        "province" => ""
        ];
    array_unshift($provinceJson,$arrEmty);    
    return $provinceJson;
}
```